# Background NSURLSession with lots of files and wsse HTTPS header for authentication

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I'm getting pretty crazy with a feature I'm implementing on my iOS application :/

I'm attempting to add for the user the possibility to download some documents on the application so that he can access it even while offline.

For an example, in the app the user can navigates through some categories that will lead him to the documents. In the feature, he could chose to download the category A. The app will download all content that's in that category from the server, and the documents.

A category can go from some tens of files to some thousands! That's why we chosed to download the contents even if the app is in the background.

So here is how it works under the hood using NSURLSession:
I have an NSObject I called DownloadManager which handle the delegation for the NSURLSession, and the session itself. When I instantiate it, I create the session with the background configuration.
I process the category I want to download to get anything I need to create the download task and launch it.
When it finishes a category has subcategories and so on (for a depth of 3 level max) that I also have to download to get all of their informations.

The thing is that I can't juste put the tasks in the NSURLSession as soon as I have one because the server uses a wsse authentication system to allowing GET the routes. This header has a 5 minutes life time, so I have to create it really just before it goes to the NSURLSession object and to be (almost) sure it sends it directly after, I limit the number of tasks in the NSURLSession to the limit of simultaneous connections per host.

In Debug mode (compiling and launching with XCode), the app works fine and does not seems to have troubles running download tasks in the background, but as I test it in Testing Mode (using Crashlytics), the processing in the background is really much slower, and sometimes it seems that the NSURLSession just does not appear to be sending events anymore...

Is there anything tricky to understand that I didn't get for using NSURLSession ? Is it normal that the session works fine in the background and then suddenly seems to be dead and doesn't sends events for more or less long time (it can long from some seconds to whole minutes!) to "work" again ? :x

Edit : The other thing is that the download works without any problem while the application is in foreground

Thank you for any help you would give me,
Bilkix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've got the answer on the Apple Developer's forum thanks to Eskimo.
I'm linking the post here, so that further developers would see the explanation easily :)

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/125217#125217